# Proving that a Galois group $Gal(E/Q)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials, splitting-field

I have seen many textbooks state this result without proof.

$``$ If $E$ is the splitting field for the polynomial $f=x^p-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ where $p$ is prime, then the Galois group $Gal(E:Q)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times} \simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p-1} . "$

I would like to know how to prove this.

The things that I know from reading are that $E=Q(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} \dots + 1$. So $E$ a cyclotomic extension of Q of degree $p-1$ and that the roots of $x^p - 1$ are the $p^{th}$ roots of unity. Also that the Galois group is comprised of the automorphisms of $E$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}$ and permute the roots of $f$.

As a second question, if I am asked to prove that the Galois group $Gal(E/Q)$ is cyclic, when $E$ is the splitting field for some specific $f$ and $p$ is small, say $5$ or $7$, is there an easier way to prove this than first proving the more general statement above and then drawing the conclusion from that?

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it. You begin your third parraph with "I know that... Also, that the Galois group...However, I am unsure how to prove this result". So you **know** it but you can't prove it? Or how can you know it but you can't prove it? So finally, what is **the question** here?

Comment: I stated the things that I think I know so that someone answering knows the extent or lack of what I am already familiar with. My question is how can I prove the statement in quotations?

Comment: @Timbuc: Nowadays, people "know" something when they have read it somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Okay. I don't know a single thing. Some help would still be appreciated though if anybody has any

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Hehe...yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 2):

If, as you say, you already know what you wrote there, then you've already proved what you need...almost.

Let $\;\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}\;$ , then $\;\zeta\;$ is clearly a root of $\;f(x)=x^p-1\;$ . Observe (well, **prove**) now that

1) All the roots of $\;f(x)\;$ are different (hint: look at $\;f'(x)\;$ )

2) $\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\;\left(\zeta^k\right)^p=1\;$

Deduce then that $\;[\Bbb Q(\zeta):\Bbb Q]=p-1\;$ and that $\;\Bbb Q(\zeta)\;$ is the  splitting field of $\;f(x)\;$ over the rationals. Also, from (2) it follows this extension is cyclic.

Comment: Shouldn't the degree of the splitting field for f(x) be p-1?

Comment: @aew1324 Of course, that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: All good. Thanks for your help. I had been forgetting a few things that were preventing it all from clicking for me.

Comment: @aew1324 My pleasure. Observe that things get even easier if you  show that all the roots of $\;f(x)\;$ are in fact a subgroup of the multiplicative group of the field $\;\Bbb C\;$  and thus a cyclic one.