# Show Gal(f) is cyclic

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

> Let K be a finite field and $f\in K[X] $ and irreducible with $deg(g)=m$.
>   Show (1) f is seperable over K and (2) $Gal(f)$ is cyclic with $|Gal(f)|=m$.

In the following L denotes the splitting field of f over K.

(1) K is finite $\implies$ K is perfect $\implies$ f is seperable over K

(2) K is perfect and $L/K$ is a finite field extension $\implies \exists a\in L$ primitive element so that $L = K(a)$. Ok then $|Gal(f)|=m$.

**But how to prove that Gal(f) is cyclic?**

I know that every zero of f is in the form: $k_1 + k_2a^i$ with $ i\in \{1,...,m-1\}$ and $k_1,k_2\in K$. That's where i am stuck...

Comment: You can check that if $\mid K\mid=q$, then $\sigma(z)=z^q$ (for $z$ in the extension field) will be a generator of the Galois group. Do it.

Comment: This is recurring question. See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616128/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1324714/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2530328/11619). In some (most) of the similar threads the smaller field is the prime field, but that doesn't actually make a difference. Admittedly you need to know a few bits more of Galois theory for it to be immediately clear that it doesn't. Therefore I encourage you to take a look at those other threads, and try to come up with a more specific question about which steps in the *answers* you have problems with.

Comment: (cont'd) Some of the threads that turn up in the search will have a specific polynomial $f$. But, as you can deduce from the formulation of this exercise, the only relevant pieces are that $f$ is irreducible and that we know its degree.

Comment: @Lubin Is it $f(z)=0$ for $z \in L$ and $\notin K$? Therefore $f(z^{q^k})=0$. So $\sigma (z) = z^q$ is in $Gal(f)$. And if ${\sigma}^k = id$ for a $k<m$ this implies either f not irreducible or f inseperable? That's impossible hence $\sigma$ is a generator of the galois group?

Comment: No, that’s not it at all. I mean that for any finite extension $L$ of $\Bbb F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, the squaring map sends $L$ to itself, and is an automorphism of $L$ that leaves $\Bbb F_2$ elementwise fixed. Similarly, if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$ where $\mid K\mid=q$, then the $q$-power map sends $L$ to itself, and is an automorphism of $L$ that leaves $K$ elementwise fixed.

Comment: @Lubin Yes I got that. That is why $\sigma \in Gal(f)$. And it's a generator of Galois group because there is no $k < m$ with ${\sigma}^k = id$. Btw is your q a power of a prime or a prime itself?

Comment: The number of elements of $K$: power of the prime characteristic.